# saving state in Parent component when passed from the child component- for multiple items(React Hooks)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I am looking to pass the item details from child to Parent and save as a state in parent, i am able to pass it with value, but then it all return as string , but i am wondering if there is any way to pass as object as it will help me identity with key value pair when working in parent component.

// this button is from the child component

```
        <Button name={producNumber} value={[productName, producNumber, price, desc, photo, stockQuantity, quantities[productName]]} variant="primary" onClick={(e) => {
          { addBasketitems(e) }
```

Also, i am looking to make a basket  in parent (having all the selected customer items/details, selected in child component) and as i am able to pass the product details in parent from the child(when customer click button) but with saving the state i am a bit confused, as the customer can select multiple products, i was thinking of making state as (object of each product) but then i dont know how many items will the user select and user can add more items in existing selected items too.

Any suggestion guys. thanks

snippet from the **child component**

```
const [quantities, setQuantites] = useState(initialQuantities)

 return (
    <div className="products">
      {searchProducts.map((eachproduct) => {
        let productName = eachproduct.product_name;
        let producNumber = eachproduct.producNumber;
        let price = eachproduct.price;
        let desc = eachproduct.productDescription;
        let photo = eachproduct.image_URL;
        let stockQuantity = eachproduct.stockQuantity;
        return (
          <div className="products" key={producNumber}>
            <ul >
              <li>
                <img className="products-image" src={photo} />
              </li>
              <li>{productName} </li>
              <li>
                Item No:{producNumber}(InStock:{stockQuantity})
              </li>
              <li>price:{price}£ </li>
              <li>{desc}</li>
              <li>
                <ButtonGroup aria-label="quantityofproduct">
                  <Button variant="secondary" name="subtract" value="subtract" onClick={() => decrease(productName)}
                  >
                    -
                  </Button>
                  <Button name={productName} variant="secondary">
                    {quantities[productName]} // its quantity of product that customer selected
                  </Button>
                  <Button variant="secondary" name="add" value="add" onClick={() => increase(productName)}
                  >
                    +
                  </Button>
                </ButtonGroup>
                &nbsp;
         // here below in value i am passing the product detail when customer selected that product
                <Button name={producNumber} value={[productName, producNumber, price, desc, photo, stockQuantity, quantities[productName]]} variant="primary" onClick={(event) => {
                 
                  { addBasketitems(event) }}>
```

snippet from **parent component**

// i am receiving the string(product details) from child and looking if i can somehow save it in the state that i will pass again to another child

```
function App() {

const [basketItems, setBasketItems] = useState({}) // saving here the customer selected products

const addBasketitems = (event) => {
    let x = event.currentTarget.value.split(",") // i have converted the string into array but not sure from here what i can do to save mulitple products in basketItems

}

 return (
<Home {...props} userData={userData} userstatus={siginalready} addBasketitems={addBasketitems}>
}
```

**Update:1**
// the below is the eachproduct object
[image]

[image]

**Update:2**

here the two objects are created(one with quantitiy=3 and other quantity=7)rather than one with updated quantitiy=7

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pass the whole object

```
<Button name={producNumber} variant="primary" 
  onClick={() => addBasketitems({...eachproduct, quantities[productName]})}>
```

Then save it in your parent state

```
const [basketItems, setBasketItems] = useState([]) // better to be an array
const addBasketitems = (product) => {
  setBasketItems(prevItems => [...prevItems, product])
}
```

or

Pass the object and the quantity

```
<Button name={producNumber} variant="primary" 
  onClick={() => addBasketitems(eachproduct, quantities[productName])}>
```

Then save it in your parent state

```
const [basketItems, setBasketItems] = useState([]) // better to be an array
const addBasketitems = (product, quantity) => {
  setBasketItems(prevItems => [...prevItems, {...product, quantity}])
}
```

Comment: Thanks ludwiguer, but  i am also looking to pass quantities[productName] (which is quantity of product customer selected), any suggestions please

Comment: apologies it might be i didn't make clear above, its correct that eachproduct  will not change but the quantity can be changed as its the number of item for each product(that customer selected), so when customer press submit  it will send the productdetails and the quantity to the parent component.

Comment: You can send any parameters you want, or add the quantity to the object, I updated my answer for you to see how

Comment: Thanks again , the first method comesup with object iteration error(screenshot of error above) but 2nd method does pass the product and quantity, as i can see in console.log, i can understand the quantities are now binded within the object and everytime new object comes in it will create the new index in the basketItems array. it works fine as long as the customer select quantity of product once.

Comment: i mean suppose customer bought Product A x 3 items and product B x 2 items and then if we add again Product A addition x 4 more it will create another Product A x 7 object rather than updating original Product A to 7(screenshot attached above), i guess quantity is the main factor here but not sure how we can update only quantity if product already exist. Thanks

Comment: hi ludwiguer, i am bit confused with  setBasketItems(prevItems => [...prevItems, product]) code, would you mind please explain it to me as i am struggling to understand the prevItems  bit as this something introduces here but not defined? is there specific term for these kinds of statement Thankyou